# How do I make the combobox update?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, combobox

```
# IMPORT MODULES -----------------------------------------------------------
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, ttk

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LISTS
```

**Here are the lists which are used in the comboboxes**

```
BlankLines = ["------------"]
CarBrandModel = ["------------","Audi", "BMW", "Mercedes"]
AudiModels = ["------------", "A4", "A8", "Q7", "R8"]
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#FUNCTIONS

def ModelSelectionFunction():

    CarBrandModelSelected = Var1.get()
    print(CarBrandModelSelected)
```

**Here it gets the value from the combobox, but my problem is that it does not update when I select something else from the combobox**

```
    if CarBrandModelSelected == "------------":
        CarModelBox["value"] = BlankLines
        CarModelBox.current(0)

    elif CarBrandModelSelected == "Audi":
        CarModelBox["value"] = AudiModels
        CarModelBox.current(0)

# SET SCREEN ---------------------------------------------------------------
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1350x750")
root.title("Car Showroom System")
root.configure(bg="white")

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# VAR
Var1 = StringVar()
Var2 = StringVar()
```

**Here the string variable are stored**

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
# SELECTION
SelectionFrame.grid_propagate(False)

CarBrand = Label(SelectionFrame, text="Car :")
CarBrand.grid(row=0, column=0)
CarBrandBox = ttk.Combobox(SelectionFrame, textvariable=Var1, state="readonly")
CarBrandBox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>")
CarBrandBox["value"] = CarBrandModel
CarBrandBox.current(0)
CarBrandBox.grid(row=0, column=1)



CarModel = Label(SelectionFrame, text="Model :")
CarModel.grid(row=1, column=0)
CarModelBox = ttk.Combobox(SelectionFrame, textvariable=Var2, state="readonly")
CarModelBox.grid(row=1, column=1)
ModelSelectionFunction()
```

**This calls the function in order to decide what to put into the combobox**

```
  root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please reduce the code down to the minimal amount necessary to illustrate the problem. See [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I reduced it down to a minimal amount

Comment: It's smaller, but it's not minimal. Do you really need three different car brands, each with four models for this problem? Can't you get by with one or two? Is configuring the font size necessary? Is the title of the window or the background color necessary to illustrate the problem? It seems to me, if you have a problem with a couple of comboboxes, all you need is a couple of comboboxes.

Comment: Okay I cut more of it I could, hope this is easy to see where the problem is now

Comment: do you get error message when you run it in console/terminal ? you forgot second argument (function name) in `bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", ....function_name.....)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add function name to bind

```
CarBrandBox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", ModelSelectionFunction)
```

and tkinter executes it when you select in combobox.

Because `tkinter` sends extra argument to binded function so you need to receive it in your function. I add `=None` so you can still execute it without arguments.

```
def ModelSelectionFunction(event=None)
```

---

BTW: this argument can give you selected value

```
if event:
    print(event.widget.get())
```